# How to proper minimize two loss functions in PyTorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, loss-function

I'm working on a project for a self driving model in Mario Kart 7 and I've come up with this model:

```py
class MK7AutoPilot(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.backbone = resnet18(pretrained=True)
        num_ftrs = self.backbone.fc.in_features
        self.backbone.fc = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, 1)
        
    
        self.accelerate_fc = nn.Linear(1,1)
        self.steering_fc = nn.Linear(1,1)
        self.accelerate = nn.Sigmoid()
        self.steering = nn.Tanh()

    def forward(self, inputs):
        x = self.backbone(inputs)
        x_accelerate = self.accelerate_fc(x)
        x_steering = self.steering_fc(x)
        accelerate =  self.accelerate(x_accelerate)
        steering = self.steering(x_steering)
        
        return accelerate, steering
```

I want to train this model in such a way that it outputs something like the following:

```py
img = torch.rand((1, 3, 224, 224))
acc_, steer_ = model(img)
print(acc_)
print(steer_)

>>>tensor([[0.3436]], grad_fn=<SigmoidBackward>)
>>>tensor([[0.2700]], grad_fn=<TanhBackward>)
```

where one output is simply if it should accelerate or not, and the other holds a float value for steering (that I save from a real controller while playing).

The problem could be at the model, I don't really know where the problem is, but I've came up with that code for training, and my loss is going down, but really slow

### setup

```py
lr=0.001
model = MK7AutoPilot()
device = torch.device('cuda')
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr)
scheduler = lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer,step_size=7, gamma=0.1)
accelerate_loss = nn.BCELoss() # sigmoid for accelerate or not
steering_loss = nn.HingeEmbeddingLoss() # backprop tanh (-1 to 1, float represeting the steering from left to right)
```

my input tensors iterated through the training loop looks like that:

```py
{'images': tensor([[[-1.4158, -1.4158, -1.4158,  ..., -0.9877, -0.8849, -0.8335],
          [-1.4158, -1.4158, -1.4158,  ..., -0.9877, -0.9020, -0.8335],
          [-1.4158, -1.4158, -1.4158,  ..., -0.9877, -0.9363, -0.9192],
          ...,
          [-0.7308, -0.7137, -0.5938,  ..., -0.3198, -0.4054, -0.5596],
          [-0.6623, -0.5938, -0.4739,  ..., -0.2342, -0.1828, -0.3027],
          [-0.5938, -0.5596, -0.4397,  ..., -0.1999, -0.0972, -0.0629]],
 
         [[ 0.9405,  0.9405,  0.9405,  ...,  1.1506,  1.2206,  1.3081],
          [ 0.9405,  0.9405,  0.9405,  ...,  1.1681,  1.2381,  1.3081],
          [ 0.9405,  0.9405,  0.9405,  ...,  1.1681,  1.2206,  1.2731],
          ...,
          [-0.6176, -0.6001, -0.4776,  ..., -0.1975, -0.2675, -0.4251],
          [-0.5301, -0.4601, -0.3550,  ..., -0.1099, -0.0574, -0.1800],
          [-0.4601, -0.4076, -0.3200,  ..., -0.0574,  0.0476,  0.0651]],
 
         [[ 2.6400,  2.6400,  2.6400,  ...,  2.6400,  2.6400,  2.6400],
          [ 2.6400,  2.6400,  2.6400,  ...,  2.6400,  2.6400,  2.6400],
          [ 2.6400,  2.6400,  2.6400,  ...,  2.6400,  2.6400,  2.6400],
          ...,
          [-0.5321, -0.5147, -0.3578,  ...,  0.0256, -0.0615, -0.2184],
          [-0.4624, -0.3578, -0.1835,  ...,  0.1128,  0.1651,  0.0431],
          [-0.3404, -0.2532, -0.1138,  ...,  0.1476,  0.2522,  0.2871]]]),
 'accelerate_targets': tensor(1.),
 'steering_targets': tensor(0.0349)}
```

### training code

```py
num_epoches=100
train_losses = []
val_losses = []

lowest_loss = 0.0
for epoch in range(num_epoches):
    since = time.time()
    print('Epoch {}/{}'.format(epoch, num_epoches - 1))
    print('-' * 10)
    best_model_wts = copy.deepcopy(model.state_dict())
    running_loss = 0.0
    for phase in ["train", "val"]:
        if phase == "train":
            model.train()
            description=f"[bold gold3]Training epoch {epoch}...  [/bold gold3]"
        else:
            model.eval()
            description=f"[bold blue_violet]Validating {epoch}...[/bold blue_violet]"

        for inputs in dataloaders[phase]:
            # unpack data in train_loader
            batch_images = inputs["images"]
            acc_targets = inputs["accelerate_targets"]
            steer_targets = inputs["steering_targets"]

            # adds dimensions to convert into single row tensor
            acc_targets =  torch.unsqueeze(acc_targets, 1)
            steer_targets =  torch.unsqueeze(steer_targets, 1)

            # insert data in cpu or gpu
            batch_images.to(device)
            acc_targets.to(device)
            steer_targets.to(device)

            optimizer.zero_grad()

            with torch.set_grad_enabled(phase == "train"):
                #print(phase == 'train')
                acc_out, steer_out = model(batch_images)
                acc_loss = accelerate_loss(acc_out,acc_targets)
                steer_loss = steering_loss(steer_out,steer_targets)
                loss = acc_loss + steer_loss

            if phase== "train":
                loss.backward()
                optimizer.step()

            running_loss += loss.item() # batch_size
            
        epoch_loss = running_loss / len(dataloaders[phase]) * batch_size
        
        if phase == "train":
            train_losses.append(epoch_loss)
            scheduler.step()
        else:
            if epoch_loss < lowest_loss:
                lowest_loss = epoch_loss
                best_model_wts = copy.deepcopy(model.state_dict())
            val_losses.append(epoch_loss)

        print(f"loss for {phase}: {epoch_loss}")
time_elapsed = time.time() - since
print('Training complete in {:.0f}m {:.0f}s'.format(time_elapsed // 60, time_elapsed % 60))
model.load_state_dict(best_model_wts)
PATH = './mk7-model.pth'
torch.save(model.state_dict(), PATH)
```

I'm curious and confused about where the problems can be, here is my logs from training:

```
Epoch 0/99
----------
loss for train: 34.093309251885664
loss for val: 300.5372936248779
Epoch 1/99
----------
loss for train: 31.72238786597001
loss for val: 276.8797794342041
Epoch 2/99
----------
loss for train: 31.226220181113796
loss for val: 271.58410873413084
Epoch 3/99
----------
loss for train: 31.03108867846037
loss for val: 270.08722229003905
Epoch 4/99
----------
loss for train: 30.625999049136514
loss for val: 269.0028186798096
Epoch 5/99
----------
loss for train: 30.8627737948769
loss for val: 267.3174392700195
Epoch 6/99
----------
loss for train: 30.71862326170269
loss for val: 266.6336479187012
Epoch 7/99
----------
loss for train: 30.502295343499433
loss for val: 265.1355312347412
Epoch 8/99
----------
loss for train: 30.43224671012477
loss for val: 264.53905220031737
Epoch 9/99
----------
loss for train: 30.286035286752803
loss for val: 263.33878364562986
Epoch 10/99
----------
loss for train: 30.407902667396947
loss for val: 264.2949726104736
Epoch 11/99
----------
loss for train: 30.30920204363371
loss for val: 263.34902610778806
Epoch 12/99
----------
loss for train: 30.172034514577764
loss for val: 262.19421157836916
Epoch 13/99
----------
loss for train: 30.344178099381296
loss for val: 263.6344455718994
Epoch 14/99
```

I wonder if I have big issues in some section of this project, or if really just needs much time for training, or if its not praticable at all.

Dataset that I'm using if needed to know: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_BcRvdpj6uAhKcVgrB1SCMhw16AK56sl

Comment: This is not directly related to coding, but I'm unsure of the practicality of this method. There isn't a direct relationship between the position of the kart and the steering/acc. of the input. I think reinforcement learning (Q learning) should be more suitable but will be extremely time consuming.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm building it from the top of my head to learn things properly out of tutorials or classical classification problems. I wasn't sure also if there could be a relation, but I thought that maybe the steering could be learned after convolutions learn to identifies the turns/curves

Comment: I think [super mario kart](https://www.polygon.com/2017/11/5/16610012/mario-kart-mariflow-neural-network-video) should also be a bit easier...

Comment: I worked with mario kart 64 and reinforcement learning before. I'm trying to come up with something decent in a supervised way to understand how to backprop properly multiple functions or to backprop convnets without Softmax/classification problems.